# Reading from FIFO after unlink()

Tags: c, ipc, fifo

I have created a FIFO, wrote to it and unlinked it.
To my surprise I was able to read data from the fifo after unlinking, why is that?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_BUF 256
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
    {
        /* write "Hi" to the FIFO */
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, "Hi", sizeof("Hi"));
        close(fd);

        /* remove the FIFO */
        unlink(myfifo);
    }
    else 
    {
        wait(NULL);
        char buf[MAX_BUF];

        /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
        close(fd);

        return 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's normal Unix behavior. Unliked content is kept for as long as at least one process has a at least one file descriptor that is via the kernel associated with said unliked content. It's not specific to FIFOs. It works with all kinds of files.

Comment: What is the right way to use it? When should I use the unlink call?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to unlink a file right after you open it. In fact I think it's better than unliking by name at_exit because a name is kind of a weak reference to the actual file (somebody could have replaced the file while your program ran and now your program could be removing something else than the file it had open). Unlinking + dealing with filedescriptor pointing to the unlinked content is a pretty standard way of doing things on Unix.

Comment: So it is OK to use unlink right after open/write on both reader and writer at the same time?

Comment: You only need to unlink once. The second call to unlink will fail (though, it's not like C will throw an exception). There should be no risk of unlinking prematurely because open on a fifo will only succeed once the other side calls open.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you pass the `O_NONBLOCK` flag to `open(2)`, opening a FIFO blocks until the other end is opened. From `man 7 fifo`:

> The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data
>   can be passed. Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end
>   is opened also.
>
> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode. In this case, opening
>   for read only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write side
>   yet, opening for write only will fail with ENXIO (no such device or
>   address) unless the other end has already been opened.

Which is to say, your parent / child processes are implicitly synchronized upon opening the FIFO. So by the time the parent process calls `unlink(2)`, the child process opened the FIFO long ago. So the child will *always* find the FIFO object and open it before the parent calls `unlink(2)` on it.

A note about `unlink(2)`: `unlink(2)` simply deletes the filename from the filesystem; as long as there is at least one process with the file (FIFO in this case) open, the underlying object will persist. Only after that process terminates or closes the file descriptor will the operating system free the associated resources. FWIW, this is irrelevant in the scope of this question, but it seems worth noting.

A couple of other (unrelated) remarks:

- Don't call `wait(2)` on the child. It will return an error (which you promptly ignore), because the child didn't fork any process.
- `mkfifo(3)`, `fork(2)`, `open(2)`, `read(2)`, `write(2)`, `close(2)` and `unlink(2)` can all fail and return `-1`. You should gracefully handle possible errors instead of ignoring them. A common strategy for these toy programs is to print a descriptive error message with `perror(3)` and terminate.
- If you just want parent to child communication, use a pipe: it's easier to setup, you don't need to unlink it, and it is not exposed in the filesystem (but you need to create it with `pipe(2)` before forking, so that the child can access it).