# What happens if I unlink an opened fifo pipe?

Tags: c, named-pipes, fifo, unlink, mkfifo

I am working on an implementation of named pipes client/server for school. I have asked my teacher what happens if i use unlink while either of the pipes end is still opened. He had no answer for me.

Anyone know?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but [this question's answer and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287079/reading-from-fifo-after-unlink) answer your question.

Comment: It is not as direct in its approach but certainly explains what happens!

Comment: Files are unnamed on UNIX, so that's the clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in particular happens, except the name is removed from the file system so no future processes can open the same named pipe.

The processes that has the pipe open will continue as normal.